# User language redirect + default language on root : it doesn't work

Tags: php, cookies, redirect, localization

Sorry for my approximative english.

I'm using this method to provide a redirection according user language, and keep the data in cookies:
http://dallascao.com/en/use-cookies-to-remember/

However, the redirection doesn't work if I decide to choose the domain root as the default language, like this way:

```
<?php $lang=$_COOKIE["lang"];
switch ($lang) {
case 'en':
    header('Location:  http://hawalove.com/');
    break;
case 'fr':
    header('Location:  http://www.hawalove.com/fr');
    break;
#Get the default language of the browser if no cookies are found.
default:
    $lang = getDefaultLanguage(); 
    switch ($lang) { 
    case 'fr' : 
        header('Location:  http://www.hawalove.com/fr'); 
        break; 
    default: 
        header('Location: http://hawalove.com/'); 
        break; 
    } 
    break;
}
?>
```

May you help me to achieve this ? I'd like to have english version at root (mydomain.com) and french version at mydomain.com/fr.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that "doesn't work" means "infinite redirection loops for English speakers".

All you need is a way to not redirect at all when the chosen language is English. Add an associative array which maps the supported languages to the redirect location then do this:

1. Grab `$lang` from `$_COOKIE["lang"]`.
2. If `$lang` is not a supported language (or not even set) then `$lang = getDefaultLanguage()`.
3. If `$lang` is not `'en'`, then redirect, otherwise display the English homepage without redirecting at all.

You can use the associative array for (2) and (3). The basic strategy is simple: don't redirect at all if the language ends up being English. You'd probably want to set your language cookie once you have a valid language too.